# How to solve bootstrap image zoom?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

my code:
http://dwz.cn/6LyQoG

[image]
I am trying to make thumbnails follow the background zoom.

I can not get rid of the black borders.

Please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't share any code, there is no code in the image you attached, you're just importing the CSS style sheet and there is no code

Comment: I have add code

Comment: Please put your code inline with the question. Why should anyone be bothered to click an outside link to help you?

Comment: Your link to your code isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Make your thumbnail responsive. The css property `.img-responsive`, makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element).

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's great to see people answering for the first time! I suggest using complete sentences in the future and be a little more specific in your suggestion. Also, saying "try it" is not very polite.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a working example**

here is the `html`

```
<p>Background image:</p>

<div class="zoom-bg"></div>

<p>Using nested image and <code>object-fit</code>:</p>

<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/arch">
</div>
```

here is the `css`

```
.zoom-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-bg:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-bg:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.zoom-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-img > img {  
  object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-img:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

check the working example here in [codepen](https://codepen.io/romeojathu/pen/BaLWYmG)